# Exactly position new option button in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

Is there a way of exactly positioning and sizing a new option button in VBA or a macro?

The code I am using inserts a new Option button in which ever cell is currently selected within a worksheet.

If you then run the code again it inserts a 2nd button exactly on top of the first.

It also sets the Option Buttons size to that of the selected cell.

What I need to be able to do is is to state within the code the cell where I want the new Option Button to be inserted, F15, and set the exact size of the button and the left/right & up/down position.

This is so that the Option button is always inserted in the same cell, at the same position and the same size every time.

Can this be done?

The code to create/insert the new Option Button is:

```
Sub AddOptionButton()
    With ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Add(Selection.Left, Selection.Top, 
Selection.Width, Selection.Height)
        .Name = "NewOptionButton"
        .Caption = "Green"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you want to avoid using selections in code

You can assign the range to a variable and place the button in it:

```
Sub AddOptionButton()
    Dim myRange as Range

    Set myRange = Range("C3")
    With ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Add(myRange.Left, myRange.Top, myRange.Width, myRange.Height)
        .Name = "NewOptionButton"
        .Caption = "Green"
    End With
End Sub
```

But it might be better to pass the range to a function:

```
Function AddOptionButton(myRange as Range)
    With ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Add(myRange.Left, myRange.Top, myRange.Width, myRange.Height)
        .Name = "NewOptionButton"
        .Caption = "Green"
    End With
End Function
```

Which you can call from anywhere in your `Sub`:

```
Call AddOptionButton(Range("F15"))
```

Comment: Looks good and I will try it but please forgive my ignorance when I ask this - what is myRange? is that something I have to change or do I use it as is?

Comment: `MyRange` is a variable. You can declare it like this: `Dim myRange as Range` (answer edited to reflect this)

Comment: A `Function` that doesn't make use of its return value should be a `Sub`, imo. A function is not defined by the fact that it can take arguments, it's by its ability to return a value/object. `Sub`s can take arguments just fine. So make it `Sub AddOptionButton(myRange as Range)` **or** have it return a reference to the button it created: `Function AddOptionButton(myRange as Range) as OptionButton`. Also, the `Call` statement is not needed, so you can write `AddOptionButton Range("F15")` in the last line.